# How to read large CSV file from azure blob in chunks using rest template

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-blob-storage, resttemplate

I need to read large CSV file from azure blob, process the records and store those records into Db. Currently I am using rest template to accomplish this. For small sized file it's working fine. However for large sized files it's giving out of memory error.

1. How to read large CSV files from azure blob using rest template.
2. I need to read the data in chunks.
3. Process the chunks of data and insert it to database.

Comment: We need to see code

Answer (score 1):

First tip: Do not load the file into memory. That is why you are getting out of memory exception. Instead, read it buffered.

If you are using Spring's RestTemplate, open the download stream like this:

```
InputStream fileDownloadUrlStream = new URL(downloadUrl).openStream();
return new BufferedInputStream(fileDownloadUrlStream);
```

You can try to accomplish it with this [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-download-large-file).

But there is also an Azure Storage client which you can add to Maven(or Gradle) project (check the latest versions).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
    <version>8.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Using chunks is a good approach. Here is an example of how can you use chunked blob client to download chunks of the file from Azure Storage:

```
 String connectionString = getAzureBlobStorageConnectionKeyName(accountName);
 BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
 BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerId); 
 BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);
 BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
 blockBlobClient.downloadWithResponse(new FileOutputStream(file),
                                      new BlobRange(0L, downloadSize * 1024 * 1024), // convert chunk size to MB
                                      null,
                                      null,
                                      false,
                                      Duration.ofMinutes(1L),
                                      null);
```